# Exact Target Marketing Cloud - Soap API - EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Currently I am trying to build a Custom Activity for our HubExchange app, from the custom activity I am sending a Json Data to Azure Function.

In Azure Function, I have refereed SOAP API `https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx` to look up records in the a specific data extension.

From Journey Builder, Custom Activity will push the records as the data comes in it. Data extenstion has about 2500 records, for each hit I need to look up the SOAP API and get certain information.

During the process, out of 100 request average of 60 request is getting failed and get the endpoint exception.

Below is the stacktrace,

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while 
executing function: NonPIISMS ---> 
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint 
listening at https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx that could 
accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP 
action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or  
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 
136.147.129.33:443
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, 
     SocketAddress socketAddress)
  at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, 
     Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, 
     ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& 
     exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.
  WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Can some one help me on this intermediate failure.